# Parameter get values from query

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting, query-builder

I have a dataset that returns all user IDs. There is a parameter that will get these ID options through the SSRS 2008 R2 setting:

- parameter options
- -> default values
- -> get values from a query
- -> Dataset...and value field....

Then I have another dataset that executes a stored procedure, taking a few parameters (all are single value).

Hiding the table is no problem. The problem is that the dataset is only executed once, only getting data for the first value of the parameter, whereas I wanted the dataset that executes the stored procedure to be executed for each user ID.

Comment: Could you edit the question and add some more details? For one, tell us what you've tried so far.

Comment: I edited... have more informations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see at least two options for your situation:

- [Create a subreport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160348%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), and place it inside a list. Bind the list to the dataset of User IDs and pass the User ID as a parameter to the subreport. The subreport will then execute its dataset for that user id.
- Alter the stored procedure so that it returns a User ID column as well. It'll only execute once, and return all the data for all users at once. In your table or matrix you can group on that column.

Comment: The problem is that i cant return values ​​and verify if the subreport have no data.